# sumifs- with 4 criteria not including negative values that appear in sum range. I have attempted to paste in image of formula below

Tags: excel, sumifs

**sumifs** is not including negative values when executing the formula with 4 criteria.  I have checked the formatting.  I have seen other posts referring to this issue unsure how to resolve it.

Comment: What domain is this? Is it Spreadsheet like Excel, GoogleSheet or a programming language?

Comment: This is an Excel Spreadsheet sorry I neglected that description

Comment: can you share the formular you are using with some sample data where the error occured?

Comment: It works for me in my testing.  We need a non-working example to look at.

Comment: Can you put an example that you need?